# Data partly lost or hidden on external disk

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

I have an external disk connected to MacBook via USB. From time to time the system alerts that the disk is unreadable, but sometimes it seems to connect and I can browse it in Finder, and even open some of its files with Quick Look, but some folders became empty although the disk has the same amount of free space. The Disk Utility can't repair the disk with alert: couldn’t unmount volume for repair. How can I possibly restore my data? My computer is MacBook Pro (early 2011), *OSX Yosemite (10.10)*. The disk has its own power adapter. I've tried Data Recovery app, but it doesn't see the disk file system and can't scan it, while at the same time I can open some files on the disk in Finder... I also need to force eject the disk because it never ejects normally.

I've tested the disk with the case and power adapter which work for sure (with another HD).

[image: This is how it looks in Disk Utility when the disk is unreadable]

[image: Disk information]

[image: Disk information]

Comment: I have seen this happen when the external power supply is failing to provide enough power for the drive. But it could also be a symptom of a failing disk.

Comment: I'm using the power adapter and external disk case from another disk that works, so I'm sure that the problem is in the HD itself.

Comment: Failing drive is the first suspect. It's failing to read the partition map when the `YYY` partition doesn't show. Could be a marginal block in that area. Recover the data you can when the partition mounts, then reformat and repartition which will map out bad blocks. How old is the drive in question?

Comment: The disk is about 2-3 years old. I'm interested only in the data, but the most important files are not shown even when the disk mounts. I've tried a few data recovery apps but they either don't see it, either can't unmount it the same way as Disk Utility. Could be there a way to save the data?

Comment: If data recovery apps aren't working, your options are limited. Professional data recovery service could recover it, but that's very expensive.

Comment: Yes but I hope since disk is still visible sometimes and some data is even readable, then there might be a chance to make it work for at least copying the data. As I understand there is a problem with the partition map, it may be damaged or something like that, but is there a way to fix that issue?

Comment: Drive Genius, TechTool Pro and Disk Warrior are all specialized disk repair utilities that you could throw at it. I've also used a second disk to clone the original and attempt data recovery on the clone, leaving the original intact if I need to attempt other options.

Comment: I can't clone the disk because it ejects every 1-5 minutes, I can't do anything because of that. And I'm sure that the adapter and power is okay because they work fine with another disk (the same model). I want to try connecting it via SATA into a desktop, may be that would help... But I don't understand what does this mean — the disk ejects by itself, reconnects back within a second, but all the apps can't unmount it and it can't be ejected normally, as if it was used by a program.

Comment: Rock|You|Hard Place .. Have to go back to the failing drive scenario and data recovery is going to be difficult if the drive unmounts itself. as you say. You might have better luck using `cp` in Terminal to recover what you can rather than going through the Finder/GUI since it's working directly with the filesystem. But professional data recovery is the best option if you **really** need the stuff off the drive. Just costs a lot of $$$$

Comment: I have solved the problem by connecting the disk directly via SATA to the PC with HFS+ drivers installed. The disk worked well and I copied the data to another disk. The only folder that still didn't work was one that had a dot at the end of its name, I suppose the dot was the reason because the folder showed with no dot, but when I tried to rename it the dot appeared (couldn't rename it anyway). May be it was because of PC/Windows, I'll try to connect the disk to Mac Pro later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem connecting the disk directly via SATA, I didn't have a Macintosh to install a 3.5" disk into, so I connected it to a PC with Windows 7, installing the HFS+ drivers, which allowed PC to see the disk and read (but not write) the data on it. I was able to copy the data to another external disk which I formatted into exFAT, so it could be used with OSX and Windows both. I still don't understand what was the problem with the disk, but I saved the important data, so I consider the problem solved.